# Не считывает название для файла

Tags: c

Я не знаю в чем проблема, вчера у меня все прекрасно работало, сегодня захожу в VS дошлифовать код, и файл, который должен хранить БД, отказывается открываться. Если вначале работы программы выбираю "создать новый файл, и начать работу в нем" то в названии файла записывается рандомные символы. Вот часть кода:

```
printf("Продолжить работу в старом файле?\n"
        "(1)-Да (0)-Нет, я хочу создать новый\n->");
    scanf("%d", &access_mode);

    printf("Введите название файла (name.txt)\n-> ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", fname);

    do {
        system("cls");

        if (access_mode == 1) {
            if ((cfPtr = fopen(fname, "r+")) == NULL) {
                printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ((cfPtr = fopen(fname, "w+")) == NULL) {
                printf("File could not be opened.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            access_mode = 1;
        }
```

https://ideone.com/lIQWkT

Comment: Как именно вы вводите данные? Если вы ввели символ `0`, затем сразу нажали `Enter`, то события развиваются следующим образом: 1) Ноль считывается в переменную `access_mode`, во входном потоке остаётся символ перевода строки, 2) Здесь `scanf("%[^\n]", fname)` первый же символ, который пытается считать `scanf()` — это перевод строки. Но он не соответствует маске. `scanf` завершает свою работу, не записав ни единого символа в `fname`.

Comment: @wololo ну так раньше то все работало, и название файла считывалось и открывалось. Если же я заменю ```scanf()``` на ```fgets()```, особо ничего не поменяется.

Comment: 1) `fgets()` также считывает символы пока не наткнётся на перевод строки. А ваш поток как раз с перевода строки и начинается. Перед тем как читать имя файла опустошите входной поток. `int tmp = EOF; while((tmp = getchar()) != '\n' && tmp != EOF);`. 2) `ну так раньше то все работало`. Обращение к неинициализированной переменной вызывает неопределённое поведение. Предсказать результат работы программы нельзя. Одна из возможных реализаций неопределённого поведения — «программа работает через раз».

Comment: @wololo спасибо за объяснение стало понятнее, но вот только я не до конца понимаю написанную вами строку ```int tmp = EOF; while((tmp = getchar()) != '\n' && tmp != EOF);``` Разве не проще написать ```while (getchar() != '\n');```

Comment: 1. Объявляем переменную `tmp`: `int tmp = EOF;`. Заодно и инициализировали, но в данном конкретном случае это не обязательно, можно написать и так `int tmp;`. 2) В цикле делаем следующее: a) Считываем один символ `tmp = getchar()` в переменную `tmp`. b) Если считанный символ отличен от символа перевода строки `(tmp = getchar()) != '\n'` **и** отличен от символа конца файла `&& tmp != EOF`, то выполняем очередную итерацию цикла. Обратите внимание на точку с запятой `;` после цикла.

Comment: `Разве не проще написать while (getchar() != '\n');` Проще, и это будет работать. Но в принципе во входном потоке может оказаться и символ конца файла. Например, если вы перенаправите ввод из файла. Цикл `while (getchar() != '\n');` при встрече конца файла станет бесконечным.